# Credit Card encryption techniques available and recommended libraries in java

Tags: library, java, encryption

Looking for some great Java libraries to encrypt the credit card information. Also the available encryption techniques available.

Comment: This may be a suitable place to ask about Java encryption libraries (depending on the question) but not really the best place to ask about techniques and best practice. StackOverflow and SoftwareEngineering are probably more suitable for those questions.

Comment: You might want to store the whole CC number just until the bank accepts the charge, and then delete all but the last four digits, in order to  make your DB less of a target for hackers. Also, *never* store the 3 or 4-digit CVV after authorization has been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [jasypt](https://jasypt.org)

> Jasypt is a java library which allows the developer to add basic
>   encryption capabilities to his/her projects with minimum effort, and
>   without the need of having deep knowledge on how cryptography works.